# Android - DrawerLayout + Remaining Content

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I'm having difficulty understanding the DrawerLayout.

Currently, I have a layout that is for my `Activity`. It contains Tabs, TextView - everything a normal layout should have.

I don't understand how I should fit in the `DrawerLayout` in to this layout file because according to the Docs, it needs to be at root level.

Let's say this is my layout so far:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".AppTabController">

<TabHost
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">
        </FrameLayout>
        .....
        .....
        .....
        .....
        .....
```

How do I therefore integrate a DrawerLayout like the one below in to this file?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- The main content view -->
      <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- The navigation drawer list --> 
     <ListView
         android:id="@+id/slider_list"
         android:layout_width="240dp"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="start"
         android:background="#ffffff"
         android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
         android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
         android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The above `DrawerLayout` has been taken from [this](http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/03/android-sliding-menu-navigation-drawer.html) tutorial:

Answer (score 0):

just inflate your layout in a Fragment class,and in MainActivity, instantiate your Fragment by 
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace.commit().

All in all,just learn to use fragment.